Client stalling on completing the project
I have a client that I started a job for on May 1. It is now almost August and she has made up every excuse in the world to delay reviewing the creatives and sending the revisions. We have had phone calls and multiple emails sharing the process of revisions for the agency. She still says she doesn't understand. Just two days ago she said that she has eye problems and can't review the project. Even when we ask for a phone call she delays for days saying she doesn't have time to speak with us. Should I cut my loses with this client and move on or demand my balance payment being that we have done all of the graphic elements on the package she is paying for.

Assuming this is a one person client, these clients are not the best in the long run.

No one can really make this decision for you. It's probably worth pursuing the money but not worry much about keeping the client long term. If it's less than 10k and you're in the US you could pursue payment through small claims court if you have a contract and can prove you did your part

opinion...
In the past, when I've encountered similar situations....
Invoice for time spent. For me there's typically either a 50/50 or 30/30/40 payment. So I invoice for whatever stage the project currently is sitting.
If that's questioned, I'll explain that books need to be kept updated and it's been [x days/months] since the project moved forward. I need to move on to other things while there's a delay. Invoices are for the project as it stands to date. If the project moves forward in the future, any paid invoices will, of course, be credited.
Basically I invoice so I'm not left shorted. I bill for the time I've invested. Then, if that's paid, I don't care how long the client takes to get back to me - I'm not out anything. At times, an invoice will spur them into action - realizing that it is costing them money. If they fail to pay for the time already invested in the project, then chances are it's a dead project and you may never see payment for anything.
Although 3 months is not that bad. Yes it's a delay, but I've seen much longer delays - and the client was legitimately delayed on their end but did return to complete the project.
